# Windows Forms - validation of MDI forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, validation

I'm working on a desktop application which is mostly MDI forms and their management. There are a lot of editable forms which need to be validate against different conditions (min/max length, only digits and so on..). I'm using `.NET4.0`, `Visual Studio 2010` and `C#`. Is there any more efficient way to do the validations for these forms than writing my custom validation methods for every form?

Comment: now cogitated the idea of ​​using the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx ?

Comment: Yeah, I was reading the same today but dunno..

Comment: Create Customcontrol.. so that can reuse the valdaition code